Get the info of a div after a Paragraph tag in an hidden DIV
Below is the structure of my HTML, generated within D365 Portal.
How can I store the info of the div after the paragraph tag with id="b"?
   <div class="hidden">
   <p id="a">66 message</p>
   <p id="b"></p>
<div data-wrapper="true" style="font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; font-       size:9pt">
     <div>test</div>
   </div>
<p></p>
   <p id="c">66666</p>
   </div>

I'm looking to store the test value into a variable or within the id value of b.

You can use querySelector to target the paragraph with the b id.
Then use nextElementSibling to get the div right after and finally innerText to get the expected information.
Optionnally, It may be a good idea to use trim to remove any spaces before or after that text.


const myVariable = document.querySelector('#b').nextElementSibling.innerText.trim()

console.log(myVariable)
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
<div class="hidden">
  <p id="a">66 message</p>
  <p id="b"></p>
  <div data-wrapper="true" style="font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; font-size:9pt">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p id="c">66666</p>
</div>




I am wondering why you did not add an id to the div itself.
But then we can get the b id with id selector
const myVariable = document.getElementById('b').nextElementSibling.innerText // getting the content of `test` from the div

console.log(myVariable);

document.getElementById('b').innerText = myVariable // storing in the `b` id

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

<div class="hidden">
  <p id="a">66 message</p>
  <p id="b"></p>
  <div data-wrapper="true" style="font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; font-size:9pt">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p id="c">66666</p>
</div>

